# Timeout on deleting a snapshot repository

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm running elasticsearch 1.7.5 w/ 19 nodes (12 data nodes).

Attempting to setup snapshots for backup and recovery - but am getting a 503 on creation and deletion of a snapshot repository.

```
curl -XDELETE 'localhost:9200/_snapshot/backups?pretty'
```

returns:

```json
{
 "error" : "RemoteTransportException[[masternodename][inet[/10.0.0.20:9300]][cluster:admin/repository/delete]]; nested: ProcessClusterEventTimeoutException[failed to process cluster event (delete_repository [backups]) within 30s]; ",
 "status" : 503
}
```

I was able to adjust the query w/ a master_timeout=10m - still getting a timeout. Is there a  way to debug the cause of this request failing?

Comment: You sure you're having all the nodes running on the same version of ES?

Comment: @Kulasangar yes, running a _nodes call indicates all nodes are running 1.7.5

Comment: Is there anything more in the ES server logs regarding this issue or just that single line?

Comment: I would like to see some elected master node logs from multiple days (complete log files), including those that contain the error. Also, `_cat/nodes`, `_cat/indices`, `_cat/shards` and probably others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance on this call seems to be related to pending tasks with a higher priority.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/timeout-on-deleting-a-snapshot-repository/69936/4